# Assign bug from different repo when creating a pull request

Tags: azure-devops

Say I have 2 repos...

And I have a work item (or bug, or whatever) in one repo, and my code in another repo (yes, I know it's silly, that's how my group rolls for historical reasons).

Is there a way to assign a bug from one to the other? So that when I create a PR in Repo1, I can link to a bug in Repo2?

Comment: Not an Azure user, but in general when the tools setup has limits seek a compromise. I'd open a new item in the correct repo, add a reference to it in the old item (for tracking purposes, maybe copy/link some info over if it makes sense), close the old item (since you say you can't really work on it), then work on the new item instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many ways to link work items to other objects in Azure DevOps.  [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-web-form#work-items-linked-to-git-code-development) is pretty extensive on this topic.  However, for the particular task at hand, linking code commits (I'll assume Git is in use for this example), can be done in several different ways.

1. In your commit message - By including the work item ID in the commit message prefixed with the hash mark `#` (i.e. `#12345`), when the commit is pushed to the server, the work item and commit are linked automatically.  Then, when this commit is part of a pull request that is created, the linkage is made visible as part of the pull request.
2. [Within the pull request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops#add-detail-to-your-pull-request) during creation, or afterward when edited by the creator, you can add work items directly to the pull request by searching either by ID or by keywords.
3. [Several other methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-web-form#work-items-linked-to-git-code-development) can be discovered through editing a work item or right in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Work Items created in Projects, not in Repos.

And yes, you can link to PR also work items from another projects.

Comment: How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Like link any work item in PR, just give the work item ID in the PR page.